# grouping multiple text using regular expression to group

Tags: regex, xml

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that groups and parse multiple scenarios.

I am using XML when calling my regexp.

```
<field name="access_device" count="17" delimiter="{_csv_}" edit="re=(\w+\---\w+)\S+|(\w+\_\d+)|(\w+)\d\S+|(\w+\-\w+)\S+"case="upper" allow-blank="yes" />
```

I come up with this regular expression it almost works but it omits the last character of the group i want to parse. In this regexp i have 4 groups i want to parse.

```
Group1           Group2     Group3     Group4
(\w+\---\w+)\S+|(\w+\_\d+)|(\w+)\d\S+|(\w+\-\w+)\S+
```

Text I receive from client below:

```
Future_7330
Future_7340
SNANTXWA010153021-76.200.41.6-MULTI AND MGT
SNAZTXSI01HUT1011-76.200.41.30-Unicast
SNANTXW010153021-76.200.41.6-UNICAST
IPDSLAM-HXC101260-71-71.149.53.62
CHVWTXGT---01CAB101A-71.149.53.58
ATASTXADOL0010BAY111-71.149.52.41-MULTI AND MGT
```

Text I only want my regexp to do parse below: this has to do with part of the regexp group3 `(\w+)\d\S+` if I remove `\d` it works but messes up Group4 `(\w+\-\w+)\S+` and if affects text `IPDSLAM-HXC101260` it will omit after the dash giving only `IPDSLAM`

```
Future_7330
Future_7340
SNANTXWA010153021     <-- not working correctly (it omit the last digit)
SNAZTXSI01HUT1011     <-- not working correctly (it omit the last digit)
SNANTXW010153021      <-- not working correctly (it omit the last digit)
IPDSLAM-HXC101260
CHVWTXGT---01CAB101A
ATASTXADOL0010BAY111   <-- not working correctly (it omit the last digit)
```

I am using this [regexr](http://regexr.com/3a15e) website to test my regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one with a positive lookahead:

```
^(\w+---\w+|\w+-\w+|\w+)(?=[-\n])
```

Comment: is it ok to match multiple groups, matching group 1 and group 2 http://regexr.com/3a163

Comment: you are right, the outer parenthesis are not needed. It causes a duplicate in each match.

Comment: ok I removed the other parenthesis and works fine now, I had spend couple of days trying to figure it out. Thanks this helps alot